# Debian 9 stretch-backports signature couldn't be verified

Tags: debian, backports, google-cloud, certbot

I'm  trying to install certbot on my Debian 9 server on Google compute engine VM.

Here's what I have done so far:
To add `backports repository`, I have edit the `sources.list` as:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then add this line at the very bottom of the file:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
```

After that when I run this command:

```
sudo apt update
```

it return this error:

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> W: GPG error: http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports
>
> InRelease: The following signatures couldn't  be verified because the
>   public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 8B48AD6246925553 NO_PUBKEY
>   7638D0442B90D010
>
> E: The repository 'http://ftp.debian.org/debian
>   stretch-backports InRelease' is not signed.
>
> N: Updating from such a
>   repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by
>   default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user
>   configuration details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should answer your question directly. Should even be able to copy and paste the commands.

https://rolfje.wordpress.com/2017/06/09/installing-gpg-keys-for-debian-backports/